# Sorting an array of 2n elements using a function which sorts n elements at a time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose we are given a subroutine that will sort any list of size m in place. How quickly can you sort a list of size 2m, by repeatedly calling the subroutine? How many invocations of the subroutine are necessary?

Comment: i think you're looking for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really!! I am expecting some hint to solve the problem in time complexity less than O(n^2)

Comment: How `sqrt` from title is related to question body?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me!!

Comment: May get an answer here but you may also consider posting in [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) (to be honest, it can be quite a challenge to determine [where to post a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598)).

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat more generalized question related to merge sort.

Comment: Where is your preliminary analysis, and where does it fall short?  For one thing, how do you see a straightforward algorithm in n^2 time?

Comment: @Salem Derisavi raises an excellent variation: must you call the function on a contiguous subset of the original list?  If you can specify the `m` elements to sort (put them into a list, sort that list, and put them back into the original), then the algorithm changes, yielding even fewer calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some starting hints:

- Since the sorting routine scales with the size of the list `m`, the quantity of calls needed is likely to be independent, or only lightly dependent, on `m`.
- The worst-case input is a list in reverse order.  Your major problem is the quantity of calls needed to transport the extreme values to the opposite ends of the list.

To illustrate the general brute-force solution, I'll use a list of 8 elements in reverse order and present a simple upper-bound solution:

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  sort each half (2 calls)
5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4
  sort middle (1 call)
5 6 1 2 7 8 3 4
  sort each half (2 calls)
1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8
  sort middle (1 call)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

That's a total of 6 calls.  You can see that the list is "chunked" into quarters; this will scale to a list of any size, as each quarter is internally sorted in the first pass, and those quarters then "travel" as a unit.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this solution.

Comment: What if we generalize this problem like : For a given array of size n we want to use a function SORT() which takes k elements at a time to sort them?

Comment: The solution is much like the above, with `k` expressed as a fraction of `n`.  If you want to get into algorithmic details, please post as a separate question.  Discussing it in comments or changing the current question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with 5 calls. I tried to prove it, I didn't do all the details but it seems possible. Note that this solution requires rearranging of (obviously, without comparing) elements. I'm not sure whether this is allowed.

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   sort each half (2 calls)
5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4
   sort the smaller halves (5 6 1 2) and larger halves (7 8 3 4) of each half (2 calls)
1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8
   sort the middle half (1 call)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If space is not an issue. You can create a new array of size 2m.
2. Sort the first and second half of the array with 2 calls to the
   helper function.
3. You can merge them into the new array by using the merge function from the merge sort algorithm:

   ```
   // Merge the temp arrays L and R into arr[l..r]
   //n1 and n2 are last indices of the two subarrays. 
   i = 0; // Initial index of first L subarray 
   j = 0; // Initial index of second R subarray 
   k = l; // Initial index of merged array
   while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
   { 
       if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
       { 
           arr[k] = L[i]; 
           i++; 
       } 
       else
       { 
           arr[k] = R[j]; 
           j++; 
       } 
       k++; 
   } 

   /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
      are any */
   while (i < n1) 
   { 
       arr[k] = L[i]; 
       i++; 
       k++; 
   } 

   /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
      are any */
   while (j < n2) 
   { 
       arr[k] = R[j]; 
       j++; 
       k++; 
   }
   ```